# How to run my jquery code on div that inserted form jquery code?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need your help in my code I have problem when new div inserted from jquery
 the inserted div does not apply to my jquery code  if anyone have solution please tell me 
and this my Html code

```
<input type="text" id="t" value=""/>
<a href="#" class="btn">click</a><br/>
<br/>
<div  class="profileInfoSectionwall"style="border:1px solid #ccc">
text111111

    <div class="remove" style="display: none;">
        <a class="post_remove" rel="1" herf="#">X</a>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div  class="profileInfoSectionwall"style="border:1px solid #ccc">
text222222

    <div class="remove" style="display: none;">
        <a class="post_remove" rel="2" herf="#">X</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this jquery  code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$(".profileInfoSectionwall").mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).children(".remove").show();

     });
     $(".profileInfoSectionwall").mouseleave(function(){
             $(".remove").hide();

         });

    $(".btn").click(function(){
         var s=$("#t").attr("value");
        $(this).after("<br/><br/><div class='profileInfoSectionwall' style='border:1px solid #ccc'>"+s+"<div class='remove' style='display: none;'><a class='post_remove' rel='3' herf='#'>X</a></div></div>");
    return  false;


    })



})
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `.live` function  [live in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
 $(".profileInfoSectionwall").live('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).children(".remove").show();
});

$(".profileInfoSectionwall").live('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).children(".remove").hide();
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Mona Abdelmajeed thanks this solution work with  me thanks alot

Answer (score 6):

You may want to try using the .on method so something like:

```
$(".profileInfoSectionwall").on('mouseenter', function(){
     $(this).children(".remove").show();

});

$(".profileInfoSectionwall").on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(".remove").hide();
});
```

Comment: No shady , it work fine with me :) , check your jquery version

Answer (score 3):

I created fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mXBkV/1/

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'div.profileInfoSectionwall', function(){
    $(this).children(".remove").show();
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', 'div.profileInfoSectionwall', function(){
    $(".remove").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you need in your case is the live() method as you want to handle events on currently existing OR future DOM elements (ie: created by JQuery).

So here is a working code for you :

http://jsfiddle.net/sidou/CMab3/

let me know if you want some improvement on it

Comment: Actually arunes answer is the best one. Even though I proposed .live() in my answer, I think it's better to use .on() method for best practice and stability of your code in case you upgrade your jQuery library in the future. So arunes definitely deserves the best answer.